# react how to do async in loop and then return react element

Tags: reactjs

```js
getLinkName(segments) {
    let arr = segments.split('/') // cars/honda
    let el = []
    let baseUrl = arr[0]
    arr.map(async (item, index) => {
        let name = await getCategoryNameFromSlug(baseUrl)
        baseUrl = baseUrl + '/' + arr[index]
        let i = (
            <Link to={'/' + baseUrl} key={index}>
                {name}
            </Link>
        )
        el.push(i)
    })
    console.log('el', el)
    return el
}
```

I got this function, it loop through an array. at each index. it fetches data, and then return the data and a react element.

Problem, the result I expect is an array of react element, but I got a bunch of promises

Comment: if you're doing this in the render, it won't work. you should fetch the data then save it to component's state, then render the Links from the state

Comment: Noticed, I missed your dynamically assigned baseUrl per `Link` in the sample code. Updated my answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 0):

A [common pattern in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) for cases like yours is to fetch your async data first and then save it as state, which in turn triggers a rerender of your component.

React elements are the basic building blocks used when React looks for [changes](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) and created each time the render phase is triggered (e.g. `render` method in case of class components). React can invoke `render` potentially  many times as part of its internal diffing algorithm implementation, so you better not rely on async operations in render phase - it expects a synchronous return value.

You can implement it like this for a class component:

```
class ExampleComp extends React.Component {
  state = { nameBaseUrlTuples: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getLinkName("cars/honda");
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.nameBaseUrlTuples.map((nameBaseUrlTuple, index) => (
      <Link to={"/" + nameBaseUrlTuple[1]} key={index}>
        {nameBaseUrlTuple[0]}
      </Link>
    ));
  }

  async getLinkName(segments) {
    const arr = segments.split("/"); // cars/honda
    let baseUrl = arr[0];
    const nameBaseUrlTuples = await Promise.all(
      // not sure, if you also want to iterate over first index
      // seems as first is your root path segment containing sub categories
      arr.map(async (item, index) => {
        let name = await getCategoryNameFromSlug(baseUrl);
        // You could remove this side effect by
        // using map callback's third "array" argument and
        // compose your URL with array.slice(0, index+1).join("/") or similar
        baseUrl = baseUrl + "/" + item;
        return [name, baseUrl];
      })
    );
    this.setState({ nameBaseUrlTuples });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because this is how asynchronous js works, functions run to complete, so when your getLinkName function returns, your el arr will have a bunch of promises.

Network requests in React should be done in eventListeners or on lifecycle components like componentDidMount or (useEffect if you are using hooks)

Assuming you are using a Class Component your code should look something like this

```
// make sure babel supports this or set the initial state in the constructor
state = { categoryNames: null}

componentDidMount() {
    let  baseUrl = segments.split('/')[0]
 Promise.all(segments.split('/').map((item,index) => {
    let name = await getCategoryNameFromSlug(baseUrl)
    baseUrl = baseUrl + '/' + arr[index]
    return name;

})).then(categoryNames => this.setState({categoryNames}))
}



render(){
    // here use categoryNames like you wanted to do in your question

}
```